# Does Swift have analogue of Java ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: multithreading, swift

I need in Swift make pool threads like in Java ThreadPoolExecutor.
Does Swift have it?

Comment: I don't think this is a 1:1 analogue, but Grand Central Dispatch should give you similar functionality.

Comment: I thought about it... But I need several threads that will perform the task list in order. Ie when any thread finished the task should take next task from the general list, etc. But ready-made solution I could not find it ... Must I try to write their own, or am I bad looking?

Comment: I think if you use a **private serial queue** rather than one of the global ones which I believe are concurrent, you can execute tasks in FIFO order. Take a look here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW6 - granted I've never used Thread Executor so maybe this isn't what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSOperation with NSOperationQueues are the tools you need.
You can run x-number of operations at once and create dependencies between operations.

more details:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/index.html